# Can we sort the data in one single document if the object has list of objects inside in Elastic search. I should also sort nested documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This is my query, where it does the nested sort but I want it to sort the data in item_numbers array together with the nested sort in a single query in elastic search.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "item_numbers.type": "catalog"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "path": "item_numbers"
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "item_numbers.value.keyword": {
            "order": "asc",
            "nested": {
                "path": "item_numbers"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

My output for the above query is below :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "item_numbers": [
        {
          "value": "Ball",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        },
        {
          "value": "Apple",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        },
        {
          "value": "Cat",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "item_numbers": [
        {
          "value": "Cococola",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        },
        {
          "value": "Appy",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to sort the document which contains multiple data in an array in a single document

Expected output :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "item_numbers": [
        {
          "value": "Apple",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        },
        {
          "value": "Ball",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        },
        {
          "value": "Cat",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "item_numbers": [
        {
          "value": "Appy",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        },
        {
          "value": "Cococola",
          "value_phonetic": "",
          "type": "catalog"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know what changes to be made in the query to sort to get this output?

Answer (score 0):

The global sort, even though it's nested, is only applied on the top level -- meaning the inner docs don't get sorted.

What you're looking for is [sorted `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#inner-hits):

```
{
  "_source": "sorted_item_numbers",            <--
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "item_numbers.type": "catalog"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {                          <--
        "name": "sorted_item_numbers",
        "sort": {
          "item_numbers.value.keyword": "asc"
        }
      }, 
      "path": "item_numbers"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "item_numbers.value.keyword": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "item_numbers"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the response will be slightly different from the standard `hits` but both the top-level docs will be sorted (the doc with the best `item_numbers.value` taking precedence) as well as the actual contents of the `item_numbers`.

Comment: how can I write this query in java?

Comment: I don't know. Feel free to open a new question regarding this b/c it's outside of the scope of this one.